# How to reference external library types without creating invalid imports

Tags: reinforced-typings

I need to remove the import statement generated by ReinforcedTypings, when the options `UseModules = true, DiscardNamespacesWhenUsingModules = true` are used

So I need my TypeScript to look like this

`export interface IMyTreeNode extends kendo.data.Node { ... }`

Where *kendo.data.Node* is a 3rd party js/TypeScript library - but it will resolve in my project fine.

I have been able to do this in the past using ReinforcedTypings by doing below: a fairly clever use of the options available, since `kendo.data.Node` is only in TypeScript, not C#.

```
[TsInterface(Name = "kendo.data.Node", AutoI = false)]
interface KendoDataNode { }

[TsInterface]
public class MyTreeNode: KendoDataNode { ... }
```

This worked perfectly. And produces this output

`export interface IMyTreeNode extends kendo.data.Node { ... }`

**The problem I have now is I had to change configuration** to use modules like this:

`TsGlobal(UseModules = true, DiscardNamespacesWhenUsingModules = true)`

And now with this configuration, ReinforcedTypings generates an extra line in the TypeScript output: which doesn't compile. And I cannot figure a way to get rid of it.

```
import { kendo.data.Node } from '../../kendo.data.Node';
export interface IMyTreeNode extends kendo.data.Node { ... }
```

I simply need to remove the import statement or make a valid one. It works perfectly without it.

I'm willing to use Fluent Configuration in any way - but I can't see any way of achieving this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell how it **must** look like?

Basically you can use `[TsImport]` on `IMyTreeNode` with `ImportTarget = "*"`. It must prevent RT from generation of exact import.

Btw, it is better to use `[TsInterface(Name = "Node", AutoI = false, Namespace="kendo.data")]` instead of including namespece into type name.

Comment: It must look like this `export interface IMyTreeNode extends kendo.data.Node { ... }` - your namespace suggestion is fair, but it won't work if I do that. It must say exactly as above, with nothing else ;-) If I use namespace it will say `export interface IMyTreeNode extends Node { ... }` and add an import with the namespace in it - and that won't compile because it's not referencing the 3rd party library anymore

Comment: Well, correct extends clause can be reached by using code generator, but imports cannot be changed. I will provide solution soon

Comment: Thanks, I guess the problem could be summarized in saying "be able to reference external library types in ReinforcedTypings-created types - without creating invalid imports" - I updated the title - perhaps I'll raise an issue in the GitHub repo at this point?

Comment: Yes, please do that